I created an AWS Lambda authorizer to be called before my main Lambda but keep getting {body:null} in the event of my main Lambda
I understand that AWS doesn't allow you to pass the request body to the authorizer lambda but what about the actual lambda I'm calling once the authorization is done? I'm testing in postman and passing a body but whenever I try to print the event, I see that it says body:null. Again this is my actual Lambda. Not the authorizer
